# Wordpress update crashed admin

Tags: wordpress

I recently had to change my password via database using md5 hash generator.

After, I tried to create a post but it had 'submit for review' instead of post.

So I then updated to the latest wordpress.

Now when I go to wp-admin, it just loops through the update screen. Click to update, Success, back to Click to update.

Anyone know what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps when you changed your login, you may have also changed the user level for your account.  Not having admin rights might explain why the button said "submit for review" instead of just posting your content.

Other suggestions include these posts...

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/31-upgrade-database-update-fails-and-loops?replies=11

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/continuous-redirects-to-wp-adminampreauth1?replies=39